# How to save response in a typescript object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, deserialization

I am using firebase datastorage to save my data and i dont know how to deserialize the response after i do a GET request.The response looks like :

```
 {
  "common": {
                   "john" : {  "path" : "pathto"},
                   "smith" : {  "path" : "pathto"},
                   "userx" : {  "path" : "pathto"}

        },
  "web": {
                   "john" : {  "path" : "pathto"},
                   "smith" : {  "path" : "pathto"},
                   "userx" : {  "path" : "pathto"}

        }


}
```

Is there any tool that can help me in the future or any advices for a proper deserialization?

Comment: What do you mean by deserialization? Transforming it from a string into a JS object? You can use `JSON.parse` for that. If you also want to keep some type info as well, you'll have to do a bunch of work by hand. I've written [raynor](https://github.com/horia141/raynor) some time ago to make things easier with this task.

Comment: I want to know how how to build the object that saves that json.What properties do i need in the class

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more precise. See [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to go about asking a good question. When you say "saves that json" it makes me thing about serialization, but the question was about deserialization (taking a string representation and building an object the program can use)

Comment: Yes , maybe i'm confusing the terms. What I have to do is to save that json into a typescript object so i can use it inside my application.

Comment: Yup, that's deserialization alright. Where do you get the json from? What sort of object is it after you've retrieved it? A string, an [Object]?

Comment: It is an Object. I get that after i do a GET request on the firebase database.

Comment: If it's already an Object, what else is to be done? You can do stuff like x['common']['john']['path']?

Comment: I see now that i can. But how could i loop between the objects inside the main object ( common , web ) without actually having to do something like x[common].  In other words how can i get all the properties of the object without naming them.

Comment: Try something like [`Object.keys`](https://www.google.ro/search?q=object.keys&oq=object.keys&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61j0l2.1325j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). That's another question, so better asked as a separate one.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answers